# Why is the algebra product $A\otimes A\to A$ well defined, given that we know the product $A\times A\to A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an algebra, with multiplication $M:A\times A\to A$, $(a,b)\mapsto ab$. How can we prove that the map $M':A\otimes A\to A$ given by linear extension of $M'(a\otimes b)=ab$ is well defined?

Comment: It’s bilinear because of distribution laws.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks.

Comment: The map $M: A\times A \rightarrow A$ is bilinear and thus by the universal property of the tensor product, there exists a unique linear map $M': A\bigotimes A \rightarrow A$ such that $ab=M(a,b)=M'(a\otimes b)$.

Comment: @Sjorszini Will you consider writing up an answer, so that the question is sort of "complete"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by two people in the comments, the axioms of an algebra say that multiplication $M:A\times A\to A$ is bilinear, and the universal property of the tensor product therefore guarantees that $M': A\otimes A\to A$ defined as stated in the question is a well-defined linear map.

Comment: I think it's better to call $M : A \times A \rightarrow A$ *bilinear*, because *linear* in this case usually would imply $M(a,b) = M( (a,0) + (0,b)) = M(a,0) + M(0, b)$, which is not how multiplication works.

Comment: You are right, I edited it.